# Back office processing for FX trades

Tags: fx

Can someone provide (or point me to) a summary of back office processing nuances specific to FX trading? For example, I know that there are several FX-specific risks that must be managed. They include transaction risk, translation risk, and short- and long-term exposure risks. GAAP and IFRS have published guidelines for fund and tax accounting for FX instruments. What other FX-specific nuanced processing challenges exist within the various back office functions including pricing, risk management, fund and tax accounting, clearance, settlement, custody, cash management, collateral management, and financial reporting?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Treasury Operations Handbook by Philip J.L. Parker

Link: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1446194507